# How to automatically get a bookmark icon in a webpage?

Tags: html

I am organizing my bookmarks in a webpage.

When I bookmark a page to my toolbar it automatically grabs the icon and I want that same Icon to show next to the webpage address in a **HTML** page without having to download the file and link it like I would an image?

e.g.

```
[google icon] www.google.com

[Facebook icon] www.facebook.com
```

etc etc

Comment: It's called favicon. Google it

Comment: I did but could not find the way to use the favicon in the way I wanted

Comment: Did you worked it out? Because you've checked a correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url for those icons are: `http://domain.com/favicon.ico`

**html**

```
<body>
    <img src="http://google.com/favicon.ico" height="16"/> Google
    <br />
    <img src="http://facebook.com/favicon.ico" height="16"/> Facebook
</body>
```

**A [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a3aEq/1/)!!**

Answer (score 0):

In the `<head>` section of your HTML:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href=" URL of icon here ">
```

For full browser compatibility, you must use an ICO file. Otherwise, PNG, GIF, and JPEG are widely supported by all browsers apart from Internet Explorer.